# Splitting a large txt file into 200 smaller txt files on a regex using shell script in BASH

Tags: regex, bash, shell, unix, scripting

I hope the subject is clear enough, I haven't found anything specifically about this in the previously asked bin. I've tried implementing this in Perl or Python, but I think I may be trying too hard.

Is there a simple shell command / pipeline that will split my 4mb .txt file into seperate .txt files, based on a beginning and ending regex?

I provide a short sample of the file below.. so you can see that every "story" starts with the phrase "X of XXX DOCUMENTS", which could be used to split the file.

I think this should be easy and I'd be surprised if bash can't do it - faster than Perl/Py.

Here it is:

```
                           1 of 999 DOCUMENTS


              Copyright 2011 Virginian-Pilot Companies LLC
                          All Rights Reserved
                   The Virginian-Pilot(Norfolk, VA.)

...



                           3 of 999 DOCUMENTS


                  Copyright 2011 Canwest News Service
                          All Rights Reserved
                          Canwest News Service

...
```

Thanks in advance for all your help.

Ross

Comment: is that much example text necessary?

Comment: Please edit and remove about 95% of the text in your question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Split one file into multiple files based on delimiter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11313852/split-one-file-into-multiple-files-based-on-delimiter)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
awk '/[0-9]+ of [0-9]+ DOCUMENTS/{g++} { print $0 > g".txt"}' file
```

> OSX users will need `gawk`, as the builtin `awk` will produce an error like `awk: illegal statement at source line 1`

Ruby(1.9+)

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
g=1
f=File.open(g.to_s + ".txt","w")
open("file").each do |line|
  if line[/\d+ of \d+ DOCUMENTS/]
    f.close
    g+=1
    f=File.open(g.to_s + ".txt","w")
  end
  f.print line
end
```

Comment: OH and we have a winner....speed *AND* elegance I spent a really wet summer in 1997 with the O'Reilly sed/awk book. Wish I could recall all that now. I *will* go and get it tmrw. **THANK YOU**

Comment: This solution puts the matching line in the new file, which answers the question.  But if, like me, you want to put the matching line in the old file before starting the new one, you'd do this:  `awk '{print $0 > n".txt"} /text to match/ {n++}`

Comment: Note: on Mac OS X you need `gawk` from e.g. MacPorts for this to work

Answer (score 10):

As suggested in other solutions, you could use `csplit` for that:

```
csplit csplit.test '/^\.\.\./' '{*}' && sed -i '/^\.\.\./d' xx*
```

I haven't found a better way to get rid of the reminiscent separator in the split files.

Comment: I can't try right now because on windows, but csplit's man page seems to suggests using %REGEX% instead of /REGEX/ for that: 

  /REGEXP/[OFFSET]   copy up to but not including a matching line

  %REGEXP%[OFFSET]   skip to, but not including a matching line

Answer (score 1):

How hard did you try in Perl?

**Edit**  Here is a faster method. It splits the file then prints the part files.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $count = 1;

open (my $file, '<', 'source.txt') or die "Can't open source.txt: $!";

for (split /(?=^.*\d+[^\S\n]*of[^\S\n]*\d+[^\S\n]*DOCUMENTS)/m, join('',<$file>))
{
    if ( s/^.*(\d+)\s*of\s*\d+\s*DOCUMENTS.*(\n|$)//m )
    {
        open (my $part, '>', "Part$1_$count.txt") 
            or die "Can't open Part$1_$count for output: $!";
        print $part $_;
        close ($part);
        $count++;
    }
}
close ($file);
```

This is the line by line method:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open (my $masterfile, '<', 'yourfilename.txt') or die "Can't open yourfilename.txt: $!";

my $count = 1;
my $fh;

while (<$masterfile>) {
    if ( /(?<!\d)(\d+)\s*of\s*\d+\s*DOCUMENTS/ ) {
        defined $fh and close ($fh);
        open ($fh, '>', "Part$1_$count.txt") or die "Can't open Part$1_$count for  output: $!";
        $count++;
        next;
    }
    defined $fh and print $fh $_;
}
defined $fh and close ($fh);
close ($masterfile);
```

Comment: `$count` is undefined. I suspect you meant `$cnt`. Also, the first time you run through the loop `$fh` is undefined, so you'll get a `Can't use an undefined value as a symbol reference` error/warning when you try to close `$fh`.

Comment: Way over my head in Perl - not that I'm not trying... Perl , Python, R, bits of Ruby, bash, a little C++ . As well as being a jobbing Doc and trying to do some research... ta for the help.

Comment: Might as well put a check on the final close() too

Comment: @rosser - oh its not that bad in Perl. A shaved down version could be done from the command line, a so called 1 liner.

Comment: Can't use an undefined value as a symbol reference at getfile.pl line 16, <$masterfile> line 1.

Comment: @rosser - Good catch! Your right, do you know how to fix it? `defined $fh and print $fh $_;` It was just an untested example, its fixed now. I would probably write it differently for my use.

Answer (score 0):

regex to match "X of XXX DOCUMENTS" is
\d{1,3} of \d{1,3) DOCUMENTS

reading line by line and starting to write new file upon regex match should be fine.

Answer (score -1):

Untested:

```
base=outputfile
start=1
pattern='^[[:blank:]]*[[:digit:]]+ OF [[:digit:]]+ DOCUMENTS[[:blank:]]*$

while read -r line
do
    if [[ $line =~ $pattern ]]
    then
        ((start++))
        printf -v filecount '%4d' $start
        >"$base$filecount"    # create an empty file named like foo0001
    fi
    echo "$line" >> "$base$filecount"
done
```

Comment: By the way, the above is pure Bash. Also, I'm sure that Python or Perl would be much faster.

Comment: Can you do it with csplit? csplit -k -z --digits=3 --suffix='%d.TXT' --prefix=FILE *.TXT /'SPLITONTHIS'

Comment: @rosser - this is a candidate for split, don't know csplit though

Comment: @sln: `split` does fixed size output files rather than regexes. @rosser: `csplit` is a definite possibility.