# Split text file using Unix utilities, like grep and sed

Tags: git, shell, sed, grep, dynamics-nav

I'm new to Unix utilities, but trying to learn something new and trying switch my simple ruby script to some kind shell script doing the same thing. But I don't know how to approach this  task.

I need to split one big file containing several small objects. Every object starts with the line like following: `OBJECT Type Number Name`.

When I'm using Ruby I'm walking file lines, one by one if I have found pattern I start to dump lines to the file. Until I find this pattern once again.

On finish I will receive bunch of smaller files instead on one big one.

But is it possible to do the same using shell script and Unix utilities? `grep`, `sed`... without calling `perl`, `ruby`?

**EDIT**: I'm trying to develop custom **git** command and using Windows. So only utilities shipped with msysgit are available for me.

Pattern of file names for objects created is following `Type-Number.txt`.

**UPDATE**: Thanks to the @perreal I come up with following code, it does what I wanted. And hopefully other Dynmaics NAV developers working with git will find this `git object splitter` useful:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# Splits text file with multiple Dynamics NAV object into many files, one per object.
# If no input file name is given, default name (all.txt) will be used instead.
#

if [ -n "$1" ] 
then
    ALL="$1"
else
    ALL="all.txt"
fi

awk '{
    if (/^(OBJECT ).*/) {
        file = toupper(substr($2,1,3))$3".TXT"
        print > file 
    } else {
        print >> file 
    }
}' "$ALL"
```

Comment: Is awk-based solution acceptable? What form of output filenames do you want?

Comment: `csplit` (context split) may do what you need.

Comment: @igustin, yes awk is OK.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Split one file into multiple files based on delimiter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11313852/split-one-file-into-multiple-files-based-on-delimiter)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
awk '{ 
  if (/(OBJECT.*)/) {
    file = OBJECT$2$3$4
    print > file
  } else {
    print >> file
  }
}' input_file
```

Comment: I got the idea, thank you! Let me test this approach before accepting the answer.

Comment: Works a bit incorrect, since 'header line' is not passed to the output file. But this is the easy one...

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for a 'context split' command: csplit

```
$ csplit filename '/OBJECT/'
```

Comment: You mean `csplit filename /OBJECT/` but yes, you have the right idea with `csplit`.

Comment: `csplit` is not shipped with msysgit unfortunately.