# Split file by XML tag

Tags: xml, unix, tags, split, command

I have a very large xml file (1.25 GB) that I need to split into smaller files to be able to process them. The file contains linguistic data that is headed and footed by the tags:

> < text id="www.example.com>

and

> < /text>

I would like to split the larger file by these tags. So that, for example,

> < text id="www.example.com>
>
> **Hello**
>
> < /text>
>
> < text id="www.example.com>
>
> **This is**
>
> < /text>
>
> < text id="www.example.com>
>
> **An Example**
>
> < /text>

Would essentially be three different files: with the beginning and end marked by the "text" tags.
For example:

**File 1**

> < text id="www.example.com>
>
> **Hello**
>
> < /text>

**File 2**

> < text id="www.example.com>
>
> **This is**
>
> < /text>

**File 3**

> < text id="www.example.com>
>
> **An Example**
>
> < /text>

I suppose this could be done by scripting in Perl, for instance, but I'm wondering if there's any kind of "one stop shop" way to split this file using unix.

I know that the splitting command is useful to split a large file into smaller files depending on lines or file size. However, is there a similar command that permits the splitting by xml tag?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following PERL program found here: [Split one file into multiple files based on delimiter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11313852/split-one-file-into-multiple-files-based-on-delimiter)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
open(FI,"file.txt") or die;
$cur=0;
open(FO,">res.$cur.txt") or die;
while(<FI>)
{
    print FO $_;
    if(/^<\/text>/) # Added \
    {
        close(FO);
        $cur++;
        open(FO,">res.$cur.txt") or die;
    }
}
close(FO);
```

Also seems to do the trick, with no maximum cap.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

The following awk solves the problem, but unfortunately caps out at around 1000 output files

> ```
> awk '{print $0 ""> "file" NR}' RS='' input-file
> ```

Answer (score 1):

It's a lot more complicated than a simple awk command, and I don't if the file would be to big or not, but you could try using an XSLT V2.0 style sheet with `result-document` to produce all of your files.

One advantage of using XSLT over a regex is that it would have better support if the file format changes slightly or if there are attributes on the nodes you want to split with.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I will definitely check out the XSLT V2.0. style sheet. Also just for a point of reference, I agree with you about the awk (the exact error I was getting is: awk: cannot open "F1021" for output (Too many open files)