# splitting xml files using perl script

Tags: xml, regex, perl

Hi Im working on perl script to split Big xml to small chunks. And i have refereed this link 
[Split file by XML tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15503980/split-file-by-xml-tag)

and my code is like this

```
if($line =~ /^</row>/)
{
$count++;
}
```

but im getting this error

```
 works\filesplit.pl line 20.
Bareword found where operator expected at E:\Work\perl works\filesplit.pl line 2
0, near "/^</row"
        (Missing operator before row?)
syntax error at E:\Work\perl works\filesplit.pl line 20, near "/^</row"
Search pattern not terminated at E:\Work\perl works\filesplit.pl line 20.
```

Can anyone help me

Update

```
<row>
  <date></date>
  <ForeignpostingId />
  <country>11</country>
  <domain>http://www.xxxx.com</domain>
  <domainid>20813</domainid>
 </row>
 <row>
  <date></date>
  <ForeignpostingId />
  <country>11</country>
  <domain>http://www.xxxx.com</domain>
  <domainid>20813</domainid>
 </row>
 <row>
  <date></date>
  <ForeignpostingId />
  <country>11</country>
  <domain>http://www.xxxx.com</domain>
  <domainid>20813</domainid>
 </row>
```

Comment: How do you want the file 'chunked' and what do you want to do with those chunks?

Comment: @Kenosis...  "Five" <row> ........ </row>  to be chunked in single file

Comment: @Kenosis .. Actually my file size is too large so i want it to be chunked 5 <row>.. </row> in a single file ... <row>...</row> <row>....</row>  like this

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried [`xml_split`](https://metacpan.org/pod/release/MIROD/XML-Twig-3.44/tools/xml_split/xml_split)? It's a tool that comes with [XML::Twig](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML%3a%3aTwig) that's specifically designed to split big XML files, based on a variety of criteria (tag name, level, size).

Answer (score 2):

You need `^<\/row>` provided that you are trying to match `</row>` at the beginning of the line. Here is my test code.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $line = "</row> something";
if ($line =~ /^<\/row>/)
{
    print "found a match \n";
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
# perl test.pl 
found a match
```

**Update**

posting this update after OP provided sample data.

You need `^\s+<\/row>` in your regex because not all of them are starting at the beginning of the line. some of them have `one space` before them. hence we need to match zero or more spaces at the begining of the line before we do actual match.

code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;

while (my $line = <DATA>)
{
    if ($line =~ /^\s+<\/row>/)
    {
        print "found a match \n";
    }
}

__DATA__
<row>
  <date></date>
  <ForeignpostingId />
  <country>11</country>
  <domain>http://www.xxxx.com</domain>
  <domainid>20813</domainid>
 </row>
 <row>
  <date></date>
  <ForeignpostingId />
  <country>11</country>
  <domain>http://www.xxxx.com</domain>
  <domainid>20813</domainid>
 </row>
 <row>
  <date></date>
  <ForeignpostingId />
  <country>11</country>
  <domain>http://www.xxxx.com</domain>
  <domainid>20813</domainid>
 </row>
```

**Output:**

```
# perl test.pl 
found a match 
found a match 
found a match
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the following will be helpful:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $i = 1;
local $/ = '<row>';

while (<>) {
    chomp;
    s!</row>!! or next;

    open my $fh, '>', 'File_' . ( sprintf '%05d', $i++ ) . '.xml' or die $!;
    print $fh $_;
}
```

Usage: `perl script.pl inFile.xml`

This sets Perl's record separator `$/` to `<row>` to read the xml file in those 'chunks' delimited by `<row>`.  It removes the `</row>` from the chunk, then writes out that chunk to a file that has the naming scheme of "File_nnnnn.xml".

Comment: Im getting blank screen . Nothing happened

Comment: Check the directory for the generated files.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/perl -w

## splitting xml files using perl script

print "Input File ? ";
chomp($XmlFile = <STDIN>);

open $XmlFileHandle,'<',$XmlFile;

print "\nSplit By which Tag ? ";
chomp($splitby = <STDIN>);

open $OutputHandle, '>','OutputFile_'.$splitby;

## to split by <user>...</user>
while(<$XmlFileHandle>){
    if(/<$splitby>/){
        print $OutputHandle "<$splitby>\n";
        last;
    }
}

while(<$XmlFileHandle>){
    $line = $_;
    if($line =~ m/<\/$splitby>/){
        print $OutputHandle "</$splitby>";
        last;
    }
    print $OutputHandle $line;
}

print "\nOutput File is : OutputFile_$splitby\n";
```