# process myslqdump file choosing only necessary databases

Tags: mysql, debian

I have full log of all databases and tables from mysql from my old server. it takes 800mb. (i run mysqldump to dump all data)
i want to restore into new server only 2 databases, each having several tables;

i need an advice how could i process this fils with minimal effort to put only say "database1" and "database2" into my new server mysql.

i was thinking about importing all of them and then dropping unnecessary, but this way i'll override "mysql" system database, which i don't want to.

i'm on debian linux and i can't even edit this 800mb file as its too large.

and as it is server , i have only ssh access to it. no GUI.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your dump contains 10 databases then couldn't you run:

```
mysql -u username -p database_name_1 < file.sql
mysql -u username -p database_name_2 < file.sql
```

This would then import just database_name_1 and database_name_2

Comment: well, this will import _ALL_ data from my database_dump.sql file. but i need to import only 2 of them, not all.

and besides this, as i mentioned, this will overwrite "mysql" database, which i don't want to overwrite. 

i could do this if i can filter out "mysql" db

Comment: I've edited my answer. Wouldn't this do the job? Maybe I've misunderstood?

Answer (score 0):

well, i used this advice
[Split one file into multiple files based on delimiter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11313852/split-one-file-into-multiple-files-based-on-delimiter)
to split my file into multiple files, one per database, using "Dumping routines for database" as delimiter.
and after some cleaning and renaming i got 1 sql file per database so i'm able to import my two databases separately.