# Grep/awk single or multiple lines based on a defined pattern (begin from a pattern and end at defined pattern)

Tags: linux, awk, grep

I need help in "grepping" out lines beginning from "TEST FILE" to ";". I'm open to any other approach such as awk

FILE A contains the following:

```
TEST FILE ABC
this file contains ABC;

TEST FILE DEF
this file contains DEF
;

TEST FILE (DEF) this file contains (DEF);
TEST FILE DGHT this file contains DGHT;

TEST FILE 123
this file contains ABC,
this file contains DEF,
this file contains XYZ,
this file contains KLM
;
```

I want the following 5 files

File1

```
TEST FILE ABC
this file contains ABC;
```

File2

```
TEST FILE DEF
this file contains DEF
;
```

File3

```
TEST FILE (DEF) this file contains (DEF);
```

File4

```
TEST FILE DGHT this file contains DGHT;
```

File5

```
TEST FILE 123
this file contains ABC,
this file contains DEF,
this file contains XYZ,
this file contains KLM
;
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. Please show your code. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/).*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split one file into multiple files based on delimiter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11313852/split-one-file-into-multiple-files-based-on-delimiter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following `awk` may help you on same.

```
awk '/TEST/{flag=1;++i} flag{print > "file"i} /;$/{flag=""}' Input_file
```

Adding a non-one liner form of solution too now.

```
awk '
/TEST/{
       flag=1;
       ++i}
flag{
       print > "file"i}
/;$/{
       flag=""}
'   Input_file
```

Comment: Your solution works.How can I modify your solution to only give me the content of "file5"

Comment: DOWN VOTER, without giving reason for downvote will not help anyone to improve, so please mention the reason for it.

Comment: @user2008558, so if you want to print the contents of `file5` at the last of the code then use `END{system("if [[ -f file5 ]]" ORS "then" ORS "cat file5" ORS "else" ORS "file5 is not present in current directory." RS "fi")}'` before `Input_file` in above code and let me know in case of any queries on same.

Comment: Instead of the accepted solution, I'll be grateful to have a solution that will have something like -- awk ' /TEST FILE 123/  where as "TEST FILE 123" (as supposed to TEST) will be the begin search pattern and ";" will be the end search pattern and then output the result to a file (File5)

Comment: @user2008558, for simple data from specific place to another specific place following may help `sed -n '/TEST FILE 123/,/;/p'   Input_file` but it really depends on your Input_file and actual data. Feel free to open a new thread as it looks like a new question, cheers.

Comment: sed -n '/TEST FILE 123/,/;/p' Input_file did get the result I was looking for