# How to take Statistics of Different Checkpoints at different Segment in gem5 checkpoints?

Tags: gem5, checkpointing

I have created some (say 10) checkpoints with a fixed interval in the **ROI** of the **gem5** simulation for **Parsec benchmark**.

Then I tried restoring the checkpoints with the following command

```
./build/ALPHA/gem5.opt configs/example/fs.py -r 1
```

but I got the **stats.txt** file in **m5out** directory. And in that stats file the result or statistics coming in combined form for all the checkpoints.

**Q** How can I take the output for different checkpoints in a different section so that the stats for each checkpoint is visible differently?

Comment: I would just search in vim for the Nth statistics header, or use `csplit` as mentioned at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11313852/split-one-file-into-multiple-files-based-on-delimiter