# Ora2pg - Export DDL to multiple files(table wise)

Tags: postgresql, oracle, database-migration, ora2pg

I am using ora2pg to migrate schema and data from oracle to postgres database.

Is it possible to export DDL table wise? Currently it's exporting as one file with all the tables.

Comment: you can split the big file, with csplit (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11313852/split-one-file-into-multiple-files-based-on-delimiter) using the delimiter: "CREATE TABLE"

Answer (score 2):

You can not export in separate files. But you can filter what you want to export (table schema etc..) and you can include/ exclude some tables for example.

Have a look to the documentation about ALLOW / EXCLUDE here :https://ora2pg.darold.net/documentation.html#Export-type